# How to render partial in lib ruby class using render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid, render-to-string

I am writing a custom tag for Liquid and want to render a partial in the tag.  I am assuming I have to use render_to_string but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried all sorts of things, including:

```
ActionController::Base.render_to_string(:partial => 'path/to/partial')
```

But nothing seems to work.  There has to be some easy way to do this that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `render_to_string` method is an instance method:

```
ActionController::Base.new.send(:render_to_string,
                                :partial => 'path/to/partial')
```

Comment: That doesn't allow for helpers?